# How can I create a linearGradient with pdfkit

Tags: node.js, pdf, gradient, linear-gradients, pdfkit

I was looking for and example on how to use linearGradient with pdfkit - see 
https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/95
"Use doc.linearGradient and doc.radialGradient to create a gradient object, passing in the required parameters. Then call the stop method on the object to add color stops. Finally, set the fillColor to the gradient object."

This is the example I crafted:

> doc.rect(50, 50, 100, 100)
>         .linearGradient(60, 60, 90,
>   90)
>        .stop([100, 100],
>   "blue")
>        .fillColor("red",
>   1)

But I get a compile error:

> node.js:201
>           throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
>  TypeError: Object #<PDFLinearGradient> has no method
>   'fillColor

'

Thanks!

Comment: also see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-lineargradientbrush/ for c# with wpf

Comment: and have a ;ook at https://gist.github.com/mattbaker/1509145

Answer (score 1):

You are close. The error was because the `linearGradient` function returns a `PDFLinearGradient` object, and since you chained everything, the `fillColor` method is being called on the gradient rather than the document as you intended.

Also, the gradient `stop` method takes a percentage (from 0 to 1) along the line created between the two points (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) rather than an explicit position.

Here's a working example:

```
var grad = doc.linearGradient(x1, y1, x2, y2);
grad.stop(0, '#000');
grad.stop(1, '#fff');
doc.fillColor(grad);
```